# will a class be garbage collected if there exists a reference to a method of that class?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

```
public Messenger(Socket socket, string username)
    {
        sock = socket;
        controller = new SocketHandler.Controller(socket);
        controller.onReceiveData += ParseMessage;
        controller.onCloseConnection += OnCloseConnection;
    }
```

...

```
if (game == Messenger.GAME_TOKEN)
        {
            new Messenger(socket, username);
        }
```

I don't want to have to manage some reference to the new instance of the Messenger class that I create. Will the reference to the private method that I add to the onCloseConnection Action in the controller suffice to keep the Messenger instance from being garbage collected?

I could always be on the safe side and manage it but the simpler the better.

Comment: I am pretty sure it does, any reference will prevent garbage collection.

Comment: Classes are not garbage colleted. Instances are garbage collected.

Comment: Is something stopping you from trying it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-read your question, and I think that the reference to the `OnCloseConnection` method of `Messenger` *will* keep the Messenger instance alive.

Comment: What if the method returned it's own instance? Then it could be reached through Controller

Comment: Not sure I followed that.

Comment: Accidentally put messenger instead of controller. So the Messenger creates the Controller in its constructor and gives the Controller a reference to one of its methods. Say the method returns the instance of the Messenger. Then it is reachable from the Controller, and thus possibly reachable by anything else.

Comment: I think I was wrong.  I re-read your original post and now I think that if OnCloseConnection is a Messenger method as you seem to indicate, it'll keep the Messenger alive.

Comment: From the context, it's pretty clear that the method is an instance method.  If it were a static method, it would not keep it alive.

Comment: Wow thanks, guess I didn't use the right words in my google search.